# Image showing in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, browser

Here is my image code, it works in chrome , edge, IE but not Firefox. I dont have a complex site , its just simple for now.

```
<img src="C:/Users/m/Pictures/Photoshop/header.png" class="header" />
```

I did some research but nothing fixed it. I change the dashes to / , before they were the opposite way .

Comment: Could you please show us at least your code and what have you done so far so we may be able to help you.

Comment: Give some more clear explanation, otherwise no one will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the image to a seperate folder in your site directory, change the source and I think that should fix it.